# Keep GNU self-defined screen window name from auto update

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

Under GNU screen, one can use `c-a A` to give current window a name. However, screen also detect program running and it can overwrite the self-defined window name.

For example, I can specify a window name call `server log`. If I do some job control and `fg` to another job the window name will be updated to `fg`, which is not very informational.

How can I keep the self-defined window name from auto update?

Comment: screen doesn't "detect" that you ran a program. There's something in your shell configuration that is pushing updates to the title.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `zsh` without the `screen` plugin. And there is no special screen setting in my `.zshrc`

Comment: screen understands the xterm title escape sequence `^[]0;title^G` so it's not necessarily a screen-specific problem

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to ask the same question. Thank god for SO's similar questions that pop up while you're posting a question.

I'm on Centos7 and a similar thing was happening to me. Though, my system was not setting the window name to the previously invoked application name -> it was setting it to user@hostname. I noticed that the offending variable was PROMPT_COMMAND which was set in /etc/bashrc. Thus, my solution was to unset that variable in /etc/bashrc (specifically inside an if statement that pertains to screen sessions).

Comment: Apparently your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` prints the relevant escape sequence `^[]0;title^G`. If it does other things as well, you might want to remove just the printing of the escape sequence.